# Eclipse - manual install of local update site

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've got a local downloaded Eclipse update site, with the usual folder structure:

```
net.sf.eclipsecs-updatesite_7.6.0.201703111252.zip/
  content.jar
  content.xml.xz
  artifacts.jar
  artifacts.xml.xz
  p2.index
  plugins/
  features/
```

I have no access to the "Install New Software" menu voice.
Can I install the plug-in manually by moving files to the right directories?

The Eclipse version is `3.7`

Comment: In _Help > Install New Software..._ click _Add..._ and then _Archive..._

Comment: @howlger I cannot have access to that menu voice unfortunately.

Comment: Is there a `dropins` directory in the Eclipse installation directory?

Comment: @howlger Yes! Keep in mind it's Eclipse 3.7, which has a different structure compared to the 4+.

Comment: The update mechanism has been changed in Eclipse 3.4 with the so-called [p2](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Getting_Started) (your problem is not related to 3x vs. 4x). Try to put or to extract it the archive into the `dropins` folder. If this does not work, try [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Can_I_install_plug-ins_outside_the_main_install_directory%3F). There might be some p2 bugs in Eclipse 3.7 (which is pretty old), but hopefully one of the solutions will work.

Comment: @howlger dropins solution worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Great. For others I have added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to **put or to extract it the archive into the `dropins`** subdirectory of your Eclipse installation directory.

(The `dropins` folder exists since Eclipse 3.4, since the update mechanism has been changed to so-called [p2](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Getting_Started)).